# No Plugin in the WordPress Admin end, but in the plugins/ folder

Tags: permissions, plugins, wordpress

I've taken all my debugging-specific plugins from one of my Windows drive, and pasted them into my Ubuntu 14.04, but I cannot see any plugin other than the two default Akismet and Hello Dolly.

I've checked the Akismet's folder permission, and matched with others. Made them equal, but no success.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not with the folder permission then, problem is with the File Permissions underlying in each folders.

Right click on the particular Plugin folder that's not accessible from the admin end, and Click on Properties.

[image: file permission]

On the Permissions tab, click on the button <kbd>Change Permissions for Enclosed Files</kbd>, and change the properties as per your choice. I've given the Owner and the User Group the permission to Create and delete files, and Others to access files only. Click <kbd>Change</kbd>, and you are done. It will provide permissions to the files underlying each of the folders. For multiple folders, select 'em all, and do it once. :)